# How to move slides of the carousel after few seconds automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a MVC5 app, and inside one of my views I have a carousel which is defined as the code below. The point is that it shows okay, and I'm able to navigate through the slides of the carousel by either clicking the left or right arrows or using the points. But when I open the view carousel is in the first slide, and it doesn't move through its other slides. I have to make it change slide after 3 seconds, and then when it comes to the last one, to return to the first, I also want to preserve the functionality of the manual slide changing. I guess I need some JS code for it, but don't know who to achieve it, I tried some things using setInterval and adding "active" class to the next slide, but there was no luck. Here is my carousel code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="margin-top:-22px; margin-left:-15px; margin-right:-15px;">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="~/Content/img/auto.png" alt="slid0" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/img/business.png" alt="slid1" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/img/exercise.png" alt="slid2" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/img/healthcare.png" alt="slid3" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/img/lawn.png" alt="slid4" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/Content/img/hair.png" alt="slid5" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Any idea, how to solve the problem?

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/a/22430567/2333214 will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
 data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000"
```

Try this

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/8pm9gd7m/)

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" style="margin-top:-22px; margin-left:-15px; margin-right:-15px;">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/" alt="slid0" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/" alt="slid1" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/" alt="slid2" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/" alt="slid3" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/" alt="slid4" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200/" alt="slid5" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
 </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
 </a>

 </div>
```