# change to next image on click jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a responsive website, originally on full screen, i will have a content section on the left consist of 10 thumbnails, on right is the main image(when you click on any thumbnail the main image will change to what thumbnail you clicked)

On 320px width size, i removed all the thumbnails, and i want the picture(main image), to change to the next image upon each click.

So i css display:none the thumbnails on 320px width screen, and then use jquery to check, if display:none = true, activate the main image to be clickable, but now i'm stuck on how i can change to the next image upon each click. I hope i can get some information on the most simplified code that i can understand since i'm not very good.

HTML

```
<div id="sectionTwo_mainPic">
    <img class="mainPic" src="highlight1.jpg">
    <img class="mainPic" src="highlight2.jpg">
    <img class="mainPic" src="highlight3.jpg">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
//if mainPic is clicked and thumbnail is not visible, change pic to next pic in order per click
$('#sectionTwo_mainPic').on('click', function(){
    var test = $('.container #sectionTwo_thumbnail');

    if (! test.is(':visible')) {
        // not sure what to type here   
    }
});
```

So basically,
i click on image1, it hide and show image2, click and hide and show image3.. and so on
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"change pic to next pic"*..? Do you mean you want to hide the clicked one..? What exactly should happen..?

Comment: You should provide all relevant HTML markup too

Comment: yah, when example the default is highlight1.jpg, when i click on the image, it will hide highlight1.jpg and show highlight2.jpg, and so on.. @TJ

Answer (score 0):

So If you want to hide the current image and show the next one, you can try something like the following (*quick modification of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22430567/2333214)*):

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var $slider = $("#sectionTwo_mainPic"),
    $slides = $slider.find("img"),
    $firstSlide = $slides.first();

  $(".mainPic").click(function() {
    var $active = $('.active'),
      $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $firstSlide;
    $active.fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.fadeIn(1000).addClass('active');
    });
  });
})
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sectionTwo_mainPic">
  <img class="mainPic active" src="http://i46.tinypic.com/2epim8j.jpg">
  <img class="mainPic" src="http://i49.tinypic.com/28vepvr.jpg">
  <img class="mainPic" src="http://i50.tinypic.com/f0ud01.jpg">
</div>
```

Basically we set the class `active` to indicate current slide. The first slide (*or anything else you want*) is given class `active` by default in markup.

Whenever user clicks slide we check whether next slide is available or not using `$active.next().length`, If it is available we [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout) the current slide and [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein) next slide, else we we [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout) the current slide and [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein) the first slide, which we cached in `$firstSlide`

---

Side note: The code above only activates slideshow (*adds the click handler*) once all images are loaded. You can use [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) instead of [`$(window).load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event) if you don't want to wait.

Comment: is it a must to use $ or i can do it like just var slider instead of var $slider, what the difference?

Comment: @Devon It's just a name... you can use anything... I use `$` in front to indicate that it is a reference to a jQuery object, on which you can call jquery methods, that's all...

Comment: i am not home yet to test it out, i will take your answer once i tried it out! THanks a lot TJ